# Distort procedural texture along concentric circles

Tags: texturing, node-editor, procedural, distort

I'm trying to distort a procedural texture along concentric circles, so far without success. I'm not even sure how to illustrate the type of distortion I want, so search google I found this image that shows perfectly what I'd like to achieve with a Voronoi type texture:

[image]

I'd also like this pattern to work in a 3 axis coordinate system so I can use it for volume densities, so it's really distortion along concentric spheres in 3D space. Is this possible with blender nodes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this nodes to achieve a similar effect:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is good, but unfortunately it doesn't work in a 3 axis coordinate system due to the Radial gradient texture.

Comment: no problem at all

Comment: Can this be made to work as a volume material so it's the same pattern in the 3rd axis as well? Currently it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDUQ7.jpg

Comment: I didn't work that out yet, but doesn't _Length_ or a _Gradient Texture_ set to _Spherical_ provide usable 3D information?

Comment: I've been going at it, too, but no luck yet. Curious to see if you can figure it out.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Any luck with this?

Comment: @Geri No, unfortunately not. My problem is that I don't actually understand what this _Radial Texture_ in combination with _Ping Pong_ and the _Length_ does, and so I have no idea how to use the third dimension of the _Length_.

Comment: I see, thanks for trying anyway!